# Connect two raspberry Pis using USB cable or USB-serial

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, serial-communication

I'm working on a project where I need two raspberry pis to communicate and the ethernet port is not free, I'm not allowed to make any changes to the GPIO pins, and I'm forced to use the USB port due to hardware considerations. Is it possible for them to communicate using a direct USB cable, or perhaps using two USB-RS232 cables?

Thanks!

Siddharth

Answer (score 2):

I would use the TTL serial pins on the GIO header. See https://elinux.org/images/1/13/Adafruit-connection.jpg
You could create your own simple null modem serial cable - consisting of 3 jumper cables.

```
Connect pins
 6 <-->  6
 8 <--> 10
10 <-->  8
```

If you can't use the GPIO header - you can do a USB to USB connection using USBNET. http://www.linux-usb.org/usbnet/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have certain externally imposed limitations that don't allow me to make any modifications to the GPIO pins. That's why I'm forced to use the USB port.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think if I take two USB-RS232 cables and wired the transmit line of one to the receive line of the other and vice versa, I could read-write across the resulting serial connection?

Comment: Yes - you could do USB to to RS232 with a null modem cable (transmit line of one to the receive line of the other and vice versa) or two USB to Ethernet

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for them to communicate using a direct USB cable, or perhaps using two USB-RS232 cables?

You fail to mention exactly which Raspberry Pi version(s) you are using.
Only the Raspberry PI Zero can be used as a USB Gadget.

Since USB is a master-slave(s) interface & protocol, you cannot simply connect two Raspberry PI 1/2/3 boards together using USB, because that would be a master-to-master connection.
If you look hard enough for a (passive) USB Type A (male) to Type A (male) cable, you can find them, but it's a bogus connection that will not work.
There are active USB host-to-host cables (which contain a shared gadget), but support can be an issue.

You could connect a Raspberry PI 1/2/3 to a Raspberry PI Zero by USB, so long as the Zero's USB port was configured as a USB ACM CDC gadget.

However one simple solution is your alternative of installing USB-to-RS232 adapters to each board.  A null-modem cable of three wires would suffice unless you needed hardware flow-control.

An alternative solution is installing USB-to-Ethernet adapters to each board (with static IP addresses, i.e. an ad-hoc connection).  This approach provides a much faster connection than an RS-232 link, and is easily utilized by applications.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I forgot to mention which Pis I'm connecting. They're two RPi 3Bs. The USB to Ethernet option definitely sounds like a good idea. I asked Markus Schumann the same question below - Do you think if I take two USB-RS232 cables and wired the transmit line of one to the receive line of the other and vice versa, I could read-write across the resulting serial connection?

Comment: *"wired the transmit line of one to the receive line of the other and vice versa,"* -- You need at least a three-wire connection which includes ground.  *"... I could read-write across the resulting serial connection?"* -- You have to configure each serial terminal to the same attributes using the **stty** command or the termios API in a program.  You're essentially asking an XY question, because the type of *"communication"* could tilt the selection of RS-232 versus Ethernet.